# Почему возникает ошибка с path.join?

Tags: node.js

пытаюсь освоить node по этому [скринкасту](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKBkVr7FtbA&index=31&list=PLDyvV36pndZFWfEQpNixIHVvp191Hb3Gg) 
вот код

```
ar nconf = require('nconf');
nconf.argv()
    .env()
    .file({ file: path.join(__dirname,'config.json' )});

module.exports=nconf;
```

консоль выдает такую ошибку

```
/var/www/html/chatnode/config/index.js:4
    .file({ file: path.join(__dirname,'config.json' )});
                  ^

ReferenceError: path is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/chatnode/config/index.js:4:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/chatnode/app.js:4:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

объясните пожалуйста в чем суть (express поставил той версии что в скринкасте)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте задать переменную

```
var path = require('path');
```

после объявления `nconf` переменной.

У вас объявление переменной начинается с **ar**

```
ar nconf = require('nconf');
```

Это вы так скопировали или так написано в вашей программе? Исправьте должно быть **var**.